# 404 error: when calling asp.net core 2.1 API from public IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an error when I calling  IIS hosted ASP.Net Core 2.1 web API using assigned Public IP.
The API working properly in [localhot](http://192..../api/values).
But when it exposed to use in public using another [public IP](http://202..../api/values), It getting error as follows.

[Error API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHeII.png)

Please help and this is the first time I have did this.

Comment: could you share your startup class? and also did you try hitting `https` on the public IP? It might be configuration thing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text like the error message are not searchable, or accessible. They should be augmented with the text they contain, or better yet replaced by the text they contain when the image conveys no additional information.

Comment: Are you trying to run it from server? Make sure you configure route to your API right.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't touch you, but the problem solved. It was network configuring faults. Now its working nicely. Thank you all for your support.